# Strategy for unit and integration tests within the same project

Tags: express, testing, jestjs, prisma, supertest

I have a simple REST API written in Node.js, Express, and Prisma. I would like to write both unit and integration tests in Jest, where unit tests rely on a mocked Prisma client and integration tests run against a real test database.

I followed [Prisma's guide to unit testing](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing), which works well so far. However, running integration tests isn't possible because the Prisma client is mocked.

- The `jest.config.js` uses `setupFilesAfterEnv` to boostrap the [Prisma mock](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing#singleton).
- My test files are co-located with the actual source code, not within a dedicated directory.
- All tests (unit and integration) are launched via `jest --watch`.

I would like to know a good strategy to run some tests with the mocked Prisma client and some tests with the real one. So far, my ideas didn't work out (like conditionally mocking Prisma or calling `jest.restoreAllMocks()`). Do you have any suggestions/ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you had a look at this recently officially published guide of Ultimate Guide to Testing with Prisma: https://www.prisma.io/blog/testing-series-1-8eRB5p0Y8o This might help

Comment: Yeah, I went through this guide as well as the others, but they all focus on either unit or integration testing, not the combination of both in a single project.